# My Fixture is initialized more than once even though I use CollectionFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-6.0, xunit, fixtures

I am writing some test classes in `.net6` using `xUnit 2.4.1` in VS2022.

I have two assemblies:

- The first one contains the Fixture;
- The second one the tests + the collection.

What I expect is that I run into the constructor of the Fixture class just once. But what happen is to run into it different times.

Here all my codes:

First assembly, `the Fixture` class:

```
public class MyDbContextFixture 
{
    private Guid x = Guid.Empty;

    public MyDbContextFixture()
    {
        x = Guid.NewGuid();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Ctor Fixture. Guid {x}. ");
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Dispose Fixture. Guid {x}.");
    }
}
```

The second assembly, `the Collection` class:

```
[CollectionDefinition("TestsCollectionsAdmin")]
public class AdminTestsCollection : ICollectionFixture<MyDbContextFixture>
{
}
```

The second assembly, `the First Tests` class:

```
[Collection("TestsCollectionsAdmin")]
public class TestsA : IDisposable
{
    private MyDbContextFixture _context { get; }

    public TestsA(MyDbContextFixture context)
    {
        _context = context;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ctor Test class A");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test class A -> Test 1");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test class A -> Test 2");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dispose Test class A");
        _context.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

The second assembly, `the Second Tests` class:

```
[Collection("TestsCollectionsAdmin")]
public class TestsB : IDisposable
{
    private MyDbContextFixture _context { get; }

    public TestsA(MyDbContextFixture context)
    {
        _context = context;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ctor Test class B");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test class B -> Test 1");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test class B -> Test 2");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test3()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test class B -> Test 3");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dispose Test class B");
        _context.Cleanup();
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
> Ctor Fixture. Guid 2049ef03-3104-4ba1-835f-25e288041385. 
> Ctor Fixture. Guid e400b28f-50ac-4da5-a007-40bb0f608bd9. 
> Ctor Fixture. Guid e11651c5-ac58-4371-b743-3663c072b157. 
> Ctor Fixture. Guid 29e63556-fcba-444f-b20f-ef66eff87925. 
> Ctor Test class A
> Ctor Test class B
> Ctor Test class B
> Ctor Test class B
> Test class B -> Test 2
> Test class B -> Test 1
> Test class A -> Test 1
> Test class B -> Test 3
> Dispose Test class B
> Dispose Test class A
> Dispose Fixture. Guid 2049ef03-3104-4ba1-835f-25e288041385.
> Dispose Fixture. Guid e400b28f-50ac-4da5-a007-40bb0f608bd9.
> Dispose Test class B
> Dispose Test class B
> Dispose Fixture. Guid e11651c5-ac58-4371-b743-3663c072b157.
> Ctor Test class A
> Dispose Fixture. Guid 29e63556-fcba-444f-b20f-ef66eff87925.
> Test class A -> Test 2
> Dispose Test class A
> Dispose Fixture. Guid e400b28f-50ac-4da5-a007-40bb0f608bd9.
```

What I have found strange is that I go into the Fixture constructor 4 times! Not 1. Not 5 as my tests!
It is clear and it is correct I go into the cleanup 5 times. Because the dispose is called after each single test. But I do not understand why I go inside the constructor of the fixture 4 times.

You can also see that I dispose twice one of the fixture instance. The one with id `e400b28f-50ac-4da5-a007-40bb0f608bd9`.

So it seems like it works just once...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have to "abuse" this answer because it would be too long for a comment.

I've created a little sample project according to your specs and this is my test output when using `Console.WriteLine()` and Rider:

```
Ctor Fixture. Guid 40d3a0d2-cc56-48e2-93d8-fa11ed9bf647. 
Ctor Test class A
Test class A -> Test 2
Dispose Test class A
Dispose Fixture. Guid 40d3a0d2-cc56-48e2-93d8-fa11ed9bf647.
Ctor Test class A
Test class A -> Test 1
Dispose Test class A
Dispose Fixture. Guid 40d3a0d2-cc56-48e2-93d8-fa11ed9bf647.
Ctor Test class B
Test class B -> Test 2
Dispose Test class B
Dispose Fixture. Guid 40d3a0d2-cc56-48e2-93d8-fa11ed9bf647.
Ctor Test class B
Test class B -> Test 1
Dispose Test class B
Dispose Fixture. Guid 40d3a0d2-cc56-48e2-93d8-fa11ed9bf647.
Ctor Test class B
Test class B -> Test 3
Dispose Test class B
Dispose Fixture. Guid 40d3a0d2-cc56-48e2-93d8-fa11ed9bf647.
```

And this is the output when using `IMessageSink` ([see here](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output#output-in-extensions)):

```
14:03:32.420 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Ctor Fixture. Guid 18cf2abd-fedd-405d-a5d1-92d76cd6aa37.  
14:03:32.455 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Ctor Test class A 
14:03:32.460 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Test class A -> Test 2 
14:03:32.463 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Test class A 
14:03:32.463 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Fixture. Guid 18cf2abd-fedd-405d-a5d1-92d76cd6aa37. 
14:03:32.464 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Ctor Test class A 
14:03:32.464 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Test class A -> Test 1 
14:03:32.464 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Fixture. Guid 18cf2abd-fedd-405d-a5d1-92d76cd6aa37. 
14:03:32.464 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Test class A 
14:03:32.475 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Test class B -> Test 2 
14:03:32.475 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Ctor Test class B 
14:03:32.475 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Test class B 
14:03:32.475 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Ctor Test class B 
14:03:32.475 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Fixture. Guid 18cf2abd-fedd-405d-a5d1-92d76cd6aa37. 
14:03:32.476 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Test class B 
14:03:32.476 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Fixture. Guid 18cf2abd-fedd-405d-a5d1-92d76cd6aa37. 
14:03:32.476 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Test class B -> Test 1 
14:03:32.476 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Ctor Test class B 
14:03:32.476 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Test class B 
14:03:32.476 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Test class B -> Test 3 
14:03:32.476 |V| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Dispose Fixture. Guid 18cf2abd-fedd-405d-a5d1-92d76cd6aa37. 
14:03:32.476 |I| TestRunner: JetBrains.ReSharper.TestRunner.Adapters.XUnit.XUnitRunner Execution completed
```

How are you executing your tests?